# java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class weblogic 12c

Tags: java, weblogic

i am trying to deploy my legacy application in weblogic 12c(which is support java 6,7,8) but everytime its showing **java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class** ,I am not able to understand what is the exact problem and how can we solve this problem can some one help me pleas? In weblogic 10 (which supports java 4,6,7) its deployed successfully

### exception

```
<Dec 6, 2019 12:10:10,555 PM GMT> <Error> <HTTP> <WL-101216> <Servlet: "JerseyRESTService" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "CDMWeb.war".
A MultiException has 1 exceptions.  They are:
1. java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class

    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.justCreate(Utilities.java:1085)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.create(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:978)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1082)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1074)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.createApplication(ApplicationHandler.java:385)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:839)
    at com.oracle.classloader.PolicyClassLoader.innerDefineClass(PolicyClassLoader.java:686)
    at com.oracle.classloader.PolicyClassLoader.defineClass(PolicyClassLoader.java:669)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
CDMGenericJobListener:contextDestroyed Event
<Dec 6, 2019 12:10:10,708 PM GMT> <Error> <Deployer> <WL-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "43494609412439500" for task "3" on [partition-name: DOMAIN]. Error is: "weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class"
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:233)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:228)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:839)
    at com.oracle.classloader.PolicyClassLoader.innerDefineClass(PolicyClassLoader.java:686)
    at com.oracle.classloader.PolicyClassLoader.defineClass(PolicyClassLoader.java:669)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see that your app is using Jersey framework. Please refer to this page https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/RESTF/use-jersey20-ri.htm#RESTF290

If you still having trouble, try to use an updated version of Jersey framework. In this case, be aware that you have to modify your web.xml file to sue the right servlet class:

```
<servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
```